# Scala - how to refactor code in functional style

Tags: scala, refactoring, scala-cats

I have created two similar methods:

```
override def getUsers(organization: String, params: String): F[Either[CodecException, List[Users]]] = for {
    resp <- getUsersFromClient(organization, params)
    result <- Sync[F].delay(resp)
  } yield result

  override def getAnimals(url: String, params: String): F[Either[CodecException, List[Animal]]] = for {
    resp <- getAnimalsFromClient(url, params)
    result <- Sync[F].delay(resp)
  } yield result
```

And I think I should refactor them in some way to have only one method or something by `implicits`, but I do not have any idea how it should be done in a right way to keep functional style. Could you help me with that?

**EDIT:**

```
def getUsersFromClient(param1: String, params: String): F[HttpResponse] = Hammock.getWithOpts(...)

def getAnimals(param1: String, params: String): F[HttpResponse] = Hammock.getWithOpts(...)
```

This method also are similar and return `F[HttpResponse]`

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say because you didn't provide your `getUsersFromClient`, `getAnimalsFromClient`, `decodeResponseEntity`, `decodeResponseContributor`...

For examle you can try to make your method generic and higher-order

```
def get[A](s: String, params: String, getFromClient: (String, String) => ..., decodeResponse: ... => ...): F[Either[CodecException, List[A]]] = for {
  resp <- getFromClient(s, params)
  result <- Sync[F].delay(decodeResponse(resp), CodecException.withMessage("Something goes wrong while decoding response."))
} yield result
```

Comment: I tried do this but in compilation time I got an error in result list `type mismatch;
 found   : hammock.HttpResponse
 required: Either[hammock.CodecException,List[A]]
  } yield result` because `getFromClient` is a method which return `F[HttpResonse]`